# How can I smooth these folds ？

Tags: modeling, python

I used a function to move the vertices to make the top of the model smoother, but after applying the function , there are some wrinkles. How do I get rid of these wrinkles
[image][image][image]

Comment: You could try to select all and Ctrl V > Smooth Vertices, or try the Smooth brush in Sculpt mode, if it doesn't work well, you probably need to change for a better topology